# Thread pool calls blocking methods

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, threadpool

I have implemented a queue that stores elements similar to a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). On retrieval, the consumer may specify a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that is tested against the queue elements. The queue will return elements in FIFO style, but skip all elements that don't fulfil this predicate. So the returned element may not be the head of the queue. If none of the queue elements fulfil the given predicate, the `take()`-thread sleeps some time and starts over.

There are a few threads adding elements to this queue and now I need many threads that consume elements from that queue.

Adding elements is simple. But how can I "connect" this queue to a pool of workers (preferably a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with dynamic thread management) which retrieve elements from this queue and do some work?

My queue has two methods:

```
boolean add(E e);
E take(); // blocks
```

The queue implementation is basically like the example in [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html), except that it's unbounded and not backed by an array, but a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which doesn't allow duplicates and maintains insertion order.

I came up with this, but I have no clue whether that's the way to go. Do I really need this extra thread?

```
SynchronousQueue<Runnable> workQ = new SynchronousQueue<>();
ExecutorService threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 100, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQ);
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (true) {
            workQ.put(() -> process(queue.take()));
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: What you describe sounds like a task based system, i.e. you have a task queue and a bunch of workers which take tasks from the front of that queue if they are runnable (all preconditions met). As for the queue, can't you make your implementation one of `BlockingQueue` and directly pass it to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best idea. But (1) I didn't want to implement something like 25 methods and (2) the `BlockingQueue` had to contain `<Runnable>` elements, so there's some overhead (the elements had to be wrapped in an extra class that is `Runnable` and can be tested with the `Predicate`).

Comment: Well you could try and extend one of the existing implementations of `BlockingQueue` (e.g. `LinkedBlockingQueue`) or base your queue on `AbstractQueue`. Additionally your queue would either have to check the predicates itself (and thus have to know a thing or two about its elements) or delegate the checks to the elements  (in which case they'd need to be wrapped or implement some interface for the queue to use).

Comment: You seem to imply that you want the pool to have different kinds of workers that `take()` from your queue using different `Predicates`.  Is that right?  I'm _guessing_ that none of the standard thread pool implementations can be customized in that way, and you'll have to implement your own.

Comment: @jameslarge I described it like you guessed, but actually I have one fix `Predicate` that I'm passing in on queue construction.  While this fixed predicate is what I currently need, it'd be certainly nice to use different predicates on retrieval.

Comment: @Thomas You are correct. But now that I've based my queue on `AbstractQueue` it still doesn't work. The problem is that a `ThreadPool` uses `BlockingQueue<Runnable>`, so I can't get anything else than `Runnable`s from it. I don't know how I can put my queue into play :-(

Comment: Your queue could implement `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and interally use a more specialized type. Your actual tasks would then either have to implement `Runnable` (or if you like a custom interface) or internally provide a wrapper/delegate for `Runnable`.

Comment: @thomas thanks, I found a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question behind this problem is: How can you make use of a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) in combination with a queue that contains elements that are not [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)? Example:

```
BlockingQueue<String> strings = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 100, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, strings);
```

(I know that in this example the thread pool doesn't know what to do with the queued strings, but it reveals the problem somewhat better I guess. Let's just say the queue contains URLs to be retrieved.)

*Answer*:
It's not possible as the thread pool executor requires a queue of runnables (no upper bound wildcards - just plain runnables). But the queue can be changed to a work queue (`BlockingQueue<Runnable>`) such that when adding elements to the queue, a `BooleanSupplier` will indicate whether the element is available or not. This way, the enqueued element is not required to be of a certain type and can be runnable instead. Adding an element could look like this (E is Runnable):

```
public boolean add(E element, BooleanSupplier availability) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        if (data.putIfAbsent(element, availability) == null) {
            notEmpty.signal();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

And:

```
String url = "...";
queue.add(() -> wget(url), () -> unlockedStrings.contains(url));
```

And for the BlockingQueue contract:

```
@Override
public boolean add(E element) {
    return add(element, () -> Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

The thread pool must be started with some workers:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor workerPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(minWorkers, maxWorkers, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
workerPool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
```